# Optimal strategy for tossing three dependent coins

Tags: linear-programming, dynamic-programming

Suppose that I have three correlated coins. The marginal probability of Head of coin $i$ is denoted by $p_i$.

The conditional probability of head for coin $i$ given the outcomes of coin $j$ and $k$ is denoted by $p_i|x_j,x_k$, where $x_j,x_k\in\{H,T\}$. We can similarly construct the conditional probability of $i$ given $x_j$.

Each coin can be tossed at most once and you receive a \$1 for a head and -\$1 for a tail. You don't have to toss all the coins, and your objective is to maximize the total reward.

What would be the optimal sequence of tossing coins in this case?

If the coins are independent of each other, the order wouldn't matter. The optimal strategy should be "flip coin i if $p_i>\frac{1}{2}$". For the case of two coins, it can be shown that it is always the best to flip the coin with a higher marginal $p_i$. However, this doesn't have to be optimal for three coin cases. I've been thinking about this problem for a quite long time but can't come up with a general solution or an intuition that might help..

Comment: If you flip coin $i$ first, is its chance to come heads the average of the four $p_i|x_j,x_k$ or is it some number not related to those?  Similarly if you have flipped just one coin?  The search space is small enough you can just exhaust it.

Comment: @RossMillikan If $i$ is the first coin, I expect H occurs with probability $p_i$. I want to generalize the rule and see what's the optimal one when I have more coins.